# Cordova InAppBrowser eventlisteners are not working

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, phonegap-build

I have the following HTML code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    // device APIs are available
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        alert("Ready");
        var opt = 'location=no,clearcache=yes,closebuttoncaption=Back,EnableViewPortScale=yes'
        var ref = window.open('http://example.com/page1', '_blank', opt);
        ref.addEventListener('loadstart', function(event) { alert('start: ' + event.url); });
        ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function(event) { replaceCustomStyle() });
        ref.addEventListener('loaderror', function(event) { alert('error: ' + event.message); });
        ref.addEventListener('exit', function(event) { alert(event.type); });
    }

    function replaceCustomStyle() {
        alert("Custom");
        ref.executeScript({
            code: "var itm = document.querySelector('#divId'); itm.setAttribute('style','width:100%');"
        }, function() {
            alert("Element Successfully Hijacked");
        })};
</script>
```

I get the first alert message ("Ready"), but none of the rest.

I intend to use the `replaceCustomStyle` function, but I don't know if it has been called (apparently not).

I use PhoneGap Build to build the project and run the apk on a device.

What should I change?

Comment: Any luck with this. I'm facing almost the same problem?